# Adding <a> tags using styles results in dropdown error

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have added an extra style via the ckeditor.styles.js for an < a > tag. But because it is an < a > tag, the way it is displayed in the styles dropdown is wrong. CKEDITOR renders the  tag inside the < option > tag which breaks it.

The style I want to use is CTA Link, which applies an < a > tag with the class="more".

In the image below, the actual link saying CTA link doesn't work. I have to click on the weird link with no text in it to apply the style.

**Update: I have now created a Codepen that demonstrates the problem - http://codepen.io/alexjlee/pen/pEvAbP**

[image: styles dropdown error]

The HTML displayed in the  tag is:

```
<li id="cke_1461" class="cke_panel_listItem" role="presentation">
  <a id="cke_1461_option" _cke_focus="1" hidefocus="true" title="CTA Link" 
  href="javascript:void('CTA Link')" 
  onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(2625,'CTA Link'); return false;"     
  role="option"></a>
  <a class="more" href="#">CTA Link</a>
</li>
```

Is there a way to just override what CKEditor displays in the < option > element? I don't want it to render the < a > tag inside it, just a label saying "CTA Link".

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Yes, thanks I have created one at http://codepen.io/alexjlee/pen/pEvAbP and updated the orignal post

Comment: I'm afraid it's a known bug in ckeditor :) check the dup link

Comment: Ah, this bug has been open for ages... there's no workaround that you know?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but now that you know the cause you can check for a solution :)